# Ceramic Capacitor value for 24v 10A DC Motor

Tags: dc-motor, decoupling-capacitor, emi-filtering

I'm running 24v 10A DC motor in my robotic system. For eliminating the EMI, I need to use ceramic capacitors at the terminals on motor side. Can anyone suggest me the the capacitor value to be used at the motor end.

Comment: Have you measured the rms ripple current?  Choose  Cap rated for twice this ripple current

Comment: If it's a DC brushed motor, try 10 nF or 100 nF and see what happens to your EMI. It's more about the length of the leads (short) than the value of the cap.

Comment: How are you controlling your motor?